# Trying to sync 2 Owl carousels with different item no.s

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I have been using this:

http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/sync.html

But I need to make a small amend, because the 1st carousel requires 3 images displayed at once, rather than just one, and then the middle image is the one aligned with the first.

So all I've done is literally:

```
sync1.owlCarousel({
   singleItem : true,
   ...
});
```

to

```
sync1.owlCarousel({
    items : 3,
    ...
});
```

But it completely messes up the mapping?

Here:

https://jsfiddle.net/frez1nLd/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify **itemsDesktop** property. This allows you to preset the number of slides visible with a particular browser width.

```
 $("#sync1").owlCarousel({
      autoPlay: 3000,
      items : 3,
      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]
 });
```

And add two empty items to the first carousel in order to make selected item center.

```
  <div id="sync1" class="owl-carousel">
      <div class="item emptyItem"></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>1</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>2</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>3</h1></div>
      <div class="item emptyItem"></div>
 </div>
```

Here is the updated [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nighisha/h8kmove5/13/)

Comment: It still doesn't work properly. The last 2 still do nothing and the top one is still one ahead of the bottom one?

Comment: You are right. I did some changes to the fiddle. Hope this is what you meant.

Comment: I could kiss you man cheers! One thing, Is there no way of getting the 1st and last to display: 12 1 2 and 11 12 1 respectively?

Comment: You can update the slider to the v2 (or beta 2.4), to make it scroll infinitely. http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com

Comment: @NighishaJohn If i update to owl carousal 2, your fiddle is not working properly, can u pls update it?